# node.js with mssql server update record problem

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server

Could anyone take a look at this code and the error that's popping?

This is the function that's taking data from and HTML form and posting to this route:

```js
 const issueHdw = async({ serial , location , usedBy, date, pcname, winvir }) => {
        const cnx = await getConnection();
        const request = await cnx.request();
        request.input("serial", sql.NVARCHAR(50), serial);
        request.input("location", sql.NVARCHAR(50), location);
        request.input("usedBy", sql.Int, usedBy);
        request.input("receivedOn", sql.date, date);
        request.input("computerName", sql.NVARCHAR(50), pcname);
        request.input("windowsVerion", sql.NVARCHAR(50), winvir);
        return await request.query(sqlQueries.issueHdw);
      };
```

This is the sql query that takes this data and update and already existing record in the `db.hardware` table:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[hardware]
SET [location] = @location ,
   [usedby] = @usedby ,
   [receivedOn] = @receivedOn ,
   [computerName] = @computerName,
   [windowsVerion] = @windowsVerion
WHERE [serialnumber] = @serial;

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[hardware] WHERE [serialnumber] = @serial
```

This is the table columns:

```
[serialnumber],
[location],
[type],
[condition],
[usedBy],
[receivedOn],
[computerName],
[windowsVerion]
```

This is the error that pops when trying to excute:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Request.input (D:\app\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:131:18)
    at Object.issueHdw (D:\app\app\js\data\events\index.js:29:13)
    at async handler (D:\app\app\js\routes\api\events.js:41:21)
    at async exports.Manager.execute (D:\app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:60:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (D:\app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (D:\app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (D:\app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:364:32)
    at async Request._execute (D:\app\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:273:9)
```

Note: the sql command works when being executed on its own with static data.
Other functions like adding to the table work as well I'm having trouble only with this one.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly the rowcount returned from the `update` statement is confusing Node. Have you tried starting the query with `SET NOCOUNT ON; ` to see if it helps?

Comment: unfortunately its returning the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to have solved this issue by adding both name and id property to the HTML input elements. I already had names but it didn't seem to work.
the problem was that the values weren't being passed from the HTML form to the request object correctly
also I had to get the data manually from the request.payload
so instead of this

```
const vals = {a, b, ... } = request.payload;
```

I had to do this for each input field

```
const val1 = request.payload.name1
```

this seems to have solved it for me.